# Is this difficulty in Popper's notion previously known, and is it Intelligible?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Popper, in his test theory, says that a hypothesis can not be in accord with all possible observable phenomena (I lack the exact formulation). There must be something observable that falsifies (or, could falsify) a hypothesis.

This seems to assume that one must know in advance what could be observable. The thing to be tested might have a clear and distinct anchoring in a concept, in something graspable by the mind but not imaginable (visualizable properly). And yet be inarticulate in terms of its empirical appearance for the trained scientific observer.

Infinity, in some sense, is almost like this. In what sense can it stand out, and be observed, as different from all possible observable phenomena? And yet, is it wholly invalid to seek to prove it as a scientific project? It's not obvious that it couldn't be falsified in some sense. In fact, in some sense, many claim it not to exist because of the view of a limited space, limited by 'created' measurable matter. However, the exact manner of conceiving such things comes in and makes the question more demanding.

It seems necessary to clarify that this is not a question about Popper's own views, at least not primarily. The question is about his principle. Whether it is a sound. It is not aimed mainly at people who happen to have read some books by Popper, or to be familiar with him. Though this is no harm. Rather at those with a real training in philosophy. Not merely in the narrow qualified analytic philosophy now regnant in the Anglo-American sphere.

"Sometimes I wonder which is more difficult: to instill an awareness of politics in the Germans or to convey to Americans even the slightest inkling of what philosophy is all about."  Arendt

Comment: It does not assume that what is observable is known in advance, it requires the proposer to present something that can be. If they can not, then the theory is not ready for prime time as science, and needs more work. It does not mean that it can not become scientific in some distant future. "Infinity" is not a theory, or even a claim, so it is unclear what you mean. Classical physics uses calculus that relies on constructions involving infinity already. And "in some sense" can be a research project but not a theory, the latter has to spell out what the sense is.

Comment: Doesn't "something that can be" imply knowledge in advance? Namely, of what "can be." Infinity is an hypothesis about what is, about being. As in Kant's "antinomies of reason." In modern physics infinity is, of course, treated as a formal mathematical concept, and thus as a fiction (or, as still in Penrose, as a manner of true knowledge), which, is useful or not as subordinated to experimental outcome. Concept doesn't have to mean formal mathematical concept. What it means is given famously by Augustine concerning the non-imaginability of a shape with a thousand sides.

Comment: It goes to a deeper question of what measurement, as a form of observation, ultimately is presupposed to mean.

Comment: No, it does not imply such knowledge and does not go into deeper questions, they are separate. It is possible that some today's vague idea may in the future get spelled out and become testable. But if it isn't, today that it isn't a theory, today. Musings about what might or might not happen in future science, with infinity or something else, have a place in philosophy, but, by broad consensus, they are not part of science proper. So this is not a difficulty for Popper, it is something he gets right. But he did have a name for such things, "metaphysical research programs".

Comment: This is no answer. You clearly don't grasp the question.

Comment: @JosephLutz if someone doesn't grasp your question, this is either their fault for not understanding it, or your fault for not stating the question clearly enough.

Popper described the necessary condition for a theory to be considered scientific. While your concept of "Infinity" is not yet clearly formulated, to say nothing about its falsifiability, it's not a part of science. This is not a "difficulty in Popper's notion"; it may, or may not, be your own difficulty.

Comment: The question is for, as I have now specified, people with some real training in philosophy. Not the philosophy of experimental science or analytic philosophy. The content of the question is clear enough to anyone so trained.

Comment: Also, one should know, Popper meant by "metaphysical research program" investigation into historical events. That is, things that can not be repeated. Such as the coming into being of the first human being or various claims regarding tropes,the Sacrifice of Isaac and so on, in biblical reports and elsewhere.This is utterly obvious to anyone who has followed the development of the West from Plato (or prior) to the Hobbes Boyle debate where the modern sense of FACT was, in the Royal Society, worked out.  The repetition of experiment raises it from act in history, to fact. The modern development.

Comment: @conifold thanks for your comments, they are clear and useful.

Comment: Popper's notion of research program applied much broader than to history. At one point, he even classified evolution as such, psychoanalysis was such in its early stages. Speculative parts of current physics, concerning strings, multiverse and quantum gravity, are also research programs.The divide is not over whether events are repeatable, but whether the speculations offered are mature enough to make specific claims about them. And this applies to testability generally, not just to Popper's narrow construal of it as falsifiability.

Comment: "one must know in advance what could be observable." Not so; according to modern sub-atomic theories the existence of new (unseen) particles has been predicted (see Higgs-boson) **and** the possiblle ways to detect their existence accordingly. The experimental test has been performed and the outcome has been positive.

Comment: It's true one can apply his criticism about metaphysics applies also to so-called teleological principles (theories of "why"). But, infinity is no more that than in the concept of a tree. Anyway, I'm not very interested in Popper, but in the principle put over and against or judged by the standard of the truth. Which means all sort of preconceptions from the little analytic philosophy syllabus have to be put aside to enter the question from the point of view of big wolves' mouth of philosophy proper which devours all narrow little emotions and professional allegiances.

Comment: This forum is very lowbrow and bigoted.

Comment: Sometimes it is. But your question could be better phrased, I'm struggling to see quite what you're asking. I wonder if the 'difficulty' you're seeing is a result of taking his definition of a valid scientific hypothesis and generalising it to all hypotheses. This would be a mistake. .

Comment: @JosephLutz — Joseph, I am quite adept with the philosophy of science (from years of training and study), but even I find your question a bit difficult to decipher. I'll give an answer below, based on what I *think* you are asking, but please remember that if you want your question answered, you have a responsibility to clarify any confusions that arise as best you can. Casting recriminations on others does no one any good.

Answer (score -1):

I think we have to begin with the point that this is not precisely what Popper said. Popper said (following Hume, I believe) that it is impossible to make a 'factual' induction because it is impossible to see every one of the (ostensibly) infinite number of observable cases to which a theory might be applied. In that sense we can never know if a theory is *true* in the absolute sense, because there is always a possibility that some further observation might not conform to the theory's prediction. Instead, Popper turned the system around, pointing out that a theory points out observations that *cannot* happen at the same time as it points out observations that *ought to* happen: e.g., when Newton's theory of gravitation tells us a falling object *ought to* follow a parabolic path, it simultaneously precludes the object from following a triangular path, or floating off sideways, or any other non-parabolic path. Scientific progress, for Popper, is a process of **falsification**, in which researchers are looking for cases in which a theory *fails*, not seeking out confirmation or validation by looking at where the theory succeeds. He does this specifically to avoid the (ostensibly) infinite number of observations necessary for *full* confirmation or validation of a theory.

As far as this goes, this is perfectly reasonable, since the real-world applications of science are generally pragmatic. People creating technology don't really care if a theory is 'perfect', as long as the theory functions correctly within the limited contexts they are developing. There is a distinct 'good enough for engineering work' aspect to the application of science that fits well with Popper's idea of falsification.

With this in mind, Popper went on to assert that in order for something to be viewed as a proper scientific theory, there must be some empirical method for falsifying it. This is the 'demarkation' issue. The theory *must* preclude certain outcomes, which can then be tested for. If a theory is so loosely and vaguely written that any outcome whatsoever can be rationalized to be in accordance with the theory, then there is no conceivable way to falsify the theory, and the theory itself cannot be considered 'scientific.

Summarizing in bullet points:

- Theory A explicitly states X will happen
- if X happens, various Y cannot happen, so theory A implicitly states these Y cannot happen
- Theorems are developed from theory A to see if any Y can be made to happen; if so then theory A is falsified
- If there are no possible outcomes Y — outcomes that shouldn't happen under theory A — then theory A is unfalsifiable, and non-scientific

If I'm understanding the question correctly, the 'infinity' point raised isn't quite on target. Popper designed his theories with the problem of infinitudes in mind. One doesn't need to search through the (ostensible) infinity of all cases to find a falsification case; one merely needs to be able to *theorize* something that should not occur if the theory is true. If that *theorized* something can be (theoretically) operationalized into a valid experimental theorem, that is sufficient (in Popper's view) to make the a theory (potentially) falsifiable, and thereby scientific.

And just to cover all bases, I should point out that 'infinity' is a mathematical abstraction, not a real world object, and thus not subject to Popper's philosophy of science. This is true of all numbers, really. We might have one apple, one car, one marmoset, etc., but we can never have 'one' without a referent.  That's nonsensical. I can test a theory involving one marmoset empirically; I cannot do an empirical test involving 'one' in and of itself.

Popper's theory falls to pieces for other reasons:

1. Scientists simply do not behave the way that Popper's theory suggests they ought to, but science still works admirably well
2. The demarkation principle itself is non-analytical. While falsification is a useful principle, it must be something developed within the context and methodology of a particular field. Trying to apply a abstract universal principle of demarkation merely leads to polemics.

Popper is an important milestone in the philosophy of science, but he's a *historical* milestone, and not much used in modern work. He's popular with science advocates (particularly those with a bone to pick over religion, alternative medicine, or other similar activities) because he seems to give a tool that bolsters their cause, but that's politics, not philosophy.

Comment: -1: I don't think, that even for Popper, that scientific progress is the march of falsification...maybe for popper-lites.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: I don't think that's what I suggested.

Comment: How would you explain 'Scientific progress, for Popper, is a process of falsification, in which researchers are looking for cases in which a theory fails, not seeking out confirmation of validation by looking at where the theory succeeds'; as someone trained in the sciences, I find this idea baffling.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: For Popper, scientific progress occurs because people are constantly creating theories, and these theories are constantly subject to falsification, which weeds out those theories which do not conform to observations. Popper doesn't theorize much about how theories are created (at least, not in any way that disagrees with standard empiricist thinking); he's more focused on deal with the *validity* of theories.

Comment: Nevertheless, scientists are in pursuit of the truth - and not the false. He's merely pointing out something quite obvious. Presumably why everybody gets so heated about it is because its an easy and obvious idea to understand.

Comment: Which like I said, says more about them, than it says about Popper.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Look, you're not following the trajectory of the philosophy of science here. Popper is a direct response to the failure of Analytical Philosophy to create a strict mapping between mathematical logic and physical principles. Analytic Philosophy could not establish a proper system of determining 'truth', so Popper turned the problem around and created a system that ostensibly reached for truth *indirectly* by eliminating false theories.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: And I'll note in passing... whenever I hear someone say "this is so easy and obvious" in a philosophical discussion, I take it as a clear sign that they are not considering the nuances and contexts. In philosophy, the devil is always in the details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105096/discussion-between-ted-wrigley-and-mozibur-ullah).

Comment: In fact he wrote his book *The Open Society and its Enemies* for exactly this reason, and within which he accused the practioners of Platonic philosophy for the totalitarian turn in European thought, even though, as he admitted himself, that he happened to like ancient Greek philosophy. In other words, Europe, in its industrial awakening made a travesty, not only of their Christian inheritiance, but also its philosophical inheritence - basically in the scramble for gold, land & slaves.

Answer (score -1):

This is the falsifiability criterion:

> A scientific theory must be able to make predictions which may turn out to be false.

You can also define it as a formulation of Occam's razor:

> If the implications of a given theory are not observable (i.e. cannot be seen as true) then the theory is useless.

*Statements about infinity are falsifiable.* For example the statement "The universe is infinite" is falsifiable because (at least in theory) we can travel in space and reach the borders of the universe.

The same statement is not *verifiable* - that is it cannot be proven true, but that is valid for all other universal scientific statements as well - every physical law involves infinity, if not in space then at least in time.